# Why does my animation suddenly end do jarringly?

Tags: javascript, html, css, gsap

I'm quite new to this, and was following a basic tutorial to create a slinky text effect with gsap, and I noticed that when I pause my mouse cursor, there's a really jarring movement where the text suddenly shoots towards the cursor. I am unaware as to what causes it, and was wondering if anybody could tell me why that happens.

```js
document.addEventListener("mousemove", e => {
  gsap.to(".title", {
    x: e.clientX,
    y: e.clientY,
    stagger: -.02,

  })
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #111111;
}

.title {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-size: 12vw;
  font-weight: 600;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 2px rgb(238, 238, 238);
  color: #111111;
  transition: all 100ms ease-in;
  user-select: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display: block;
}

#title-container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.5.1/gsap.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="title-container">
    <div class="title">Def(x)</div>
    <div class="title">Def(x)</div>
    <div class="title">Def(x)</div>
    <div class="title">Def(x)</div>
    <div class="title">Def(x)</div>
  </div>

</body>
```

I want to try and prevent this end magnetism, and I'm not sure what's causing it. I've tried messing around with ease functions but that doesn't seem to affect it in the least. Is there something fundamentally wrong with the code that's causing it to happen? Is there a better way of doing this entirely? Help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: If you want to slow the animation, change `transition: all 100ms ease-in;` to `transition: all 500ms ease;` or a higher ms value in your CSS.

Comment: I highly recommend reading the [most common GSAP mistakes article](https://greensock.com/mistakes/) because you're making one of them :)

Comment: As covered [in the GreenSock forums thread](https://greensock.com/forums/topic/25365-how-does-gsap-animate-its-horizontal-and-vertical-movement/), we at GreenSock recommend that you set all transforms on animated elements with GSAP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you have the `transition` css property, you don't need that, it's conflicting with what `gsap` is doing. Just comment or remove it out and you're good to go

```js
document.addEventListener("mousemove", e => {
  gsap.to(".title", {
    x: e.clientX,
    y: e.clientY,
    stagger: -.02,
  })
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #111111;
}

.title {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-size: 12vw;
  font-weight: 600;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 2px rgb(238, 238, 238);
  color: #111111;
  /* transition: all 100ms ease-in; */
  user-select: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display: block;
}

#title-container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.5.1/gsap.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="title-container">
    <div class="title">Def(x)</div>
    <div class="title">Def(x)</div>
    <div class="title">Def(x)</div>
    <div class="title">Def(x)</div>
    <div class="title">Def(x)</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: well done for understanding what *suddenly end do jarringly* means

Comment: @LawrenceCherone my bad xd I meant so.